# Android back stack size

Tags: android, user-interface, fragmentmanager

We have an application, with links to various screens and reports.

On a web browser we can navigate to different pages and the pages are added to a navigation history, but I don't have to think about the back stack.  I just assume that if the history is taking too much memory, the browser would trim browsing history as needed - But it sounds like in Android we could see out of memory errors if the stack is too big?

What should I do to keep the memory footprint of the back stack reasonable but let people navigate around the application and maintain a history of their past several screens?  Is there a setting I should be looking for?  Or just a little code script I should be running?

I'd like to use whatever Android natively offers rather than trying to create something from scratch here...

Or am I thinking about the problem the wrong way?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother yourself. If system needs more memory it will destroy background activities and recreates them again when user will return to them.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html):

> When the system stops one of your activities (such as when a new activity starts or the task moves to the background), the system might destroy that activity completely if it needs to recover system memory. When this happens, information about the activity state is lost. If this happens, the system still knows that the activity has a place in the back stack, but when the activity is brought to the top of the stack the system must recreate it (rather than resume it)

Comment: Interesting - I wish I could see something that says the back stack itself is pruned as well, long after the activities they reference have been destroyed.  It seems like an infinitely growing list is always cause for concern.